# Не удаётся загрузить страницу - Gecko SDK

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь встроить Gecko в Win32 API приложение. написал следующее:

```
#define XPCOM_GLUE 1
#define XP_WIN
#include "xpcom-config.h"
#include"Win32API_Window.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "nsXPCOMGlue.h"
#include "nsCOMPtr.h"
#include "nsIBaseWindow.h"
#include "nsILocalFile.h"
#include "nsIWebBrowser.h"
#include "nsIWebNavigation.h"
#include "nsEmbedCID.h"
#include "nsEmbedString.h"
#include "nsComponentManagerUtils.h"  
#include"nsIDOMWindow.h"
#include "nsXULAppAPI.h"
#include"nsIWindowMediator.h"
#include"nsIServiceManager.h"
#include"nsIComponentRegistrar.h"
using namespace mozilla;
XRE_InitEmbedding2Type XRE_InitEmbedding;
XRE_TermEmbeddingType XRE_TermEmbedding;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{

    nsDynamicFunctionLoad nsFuncs[] = {
        { "XRE_InitEmbedding2", (NSFuncPtr*)&XRE_InitEmbedding },
        { "XRE_TermEmbedding", (NSFuncPtr*)&XRE_TermEmbedding },
        { nullptr, nullptr }
    };
    Win32API_Window window(hInstance);
    nsCOMPtr<nsIBaseWindow> baseWindow;
    nsCOMPtr<nsIWebBrowser> webBrowser;
    nsCOMPtr<nsIFile> libxul;
    nsCOMPtr<nsIWebNavigation> webNavigation;
    nsresult rv=NS_OK;
    window.createWindow(1024, 768);
    window.ShowAPIWindow();
    //Инициализация XPCOM|Init XPCOM
    rv = XPCOMGlueStartup("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xulrunner-sdk\\bin\\xpcom.dll");
    //Инициализация функций|Init functions
    rv = XPCOMGlueLoadXULFunctions(nsFuncs);
    rv = NS_NewNativeLocalFile(nsEmbedCString("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xulrunner-sdk\\bin\\xul.dll"),
        PR_FALSE, getter_AddRefs(libxul));
    rv = XRE_InitEmbedding(libxul, 0, 0);
    webBrowser = do_CreateInstance(NS_WEBBROWSER_CONTRACTID, &rv);
    baseWindow = do_QueryInterface(webBrowser);
    rv = baseWindow->InitWindow(window.getHandle(), 0, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    rv = baseWindow->Create();
    rv = baseWindow->SetVisibility(PR_TRUE);
    //Навигация|Navigation
    webNavigation = do_QueryInterface(webBrowser,&rv);
    rv = webNavigation->LoadURI(NS_ConvertASCIItoUTF16("http://www.ya.ru").get(),nsIWebNavigation::LOAD_FLAGS_NONE, NULL,NULL,NULL);
    if (rv != NS_OK) {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPSTR)"NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED", (LPSTR)"GeckoInit Error!", NULL);
        exit(__LINE__);
    }
    window.startMessageLoop();
    XRE_TermEmbedding();
    XPCOMGlueShutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

До функции "LoadURI" всё хорошо (rv=NS_OK), после попытки навигации, происходит ошибка и rv =NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED. Скажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Я думаю, что главное в программировании - это научиться  самому находить ошибки в своем коде.:)

Comment: уже несколько дней ищу.. ошибку пробивал, ничего толком не нашёл